# boost not found in electric on Linuxmint 9(based on lucid 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-lucid, boost, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running the installations and tutorial for building packages in electric (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages)  When I run the command:

```
rosdep install turtlesim
```

I get the following result:

```
Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep boost.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.40-all-dev']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}}
}}}

Failed to find rosdep boost for package turtlesim on OS:ubuntu version:10.04
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install boost
```

I've looked in synaptic and I have libboost1.40-all-dev installed.

I've tried the following with the following results:

1. I've tried installing the newest version of LinuxMint in a virtual machine, but I get the same error.
2. Installing Ubuntu 10.04 in a virtual machine. I don't get this error (however, I can't run stage because it won't work with the virtual video card).
3. Installing ROS on a Mac, this won't work because I get a whole host of problems cropping up such as not being able to py26-setuptools, or easy_install because they are "not found" when I try `sudo port install py26-setuptools`)

This is driving me completely nuts. Does anyone have any idea what I can try?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11201/boost-not-found-in-electric-on-linuxmint-9(based-on-lucid-10.04)/) by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There have been a couple of other Linux Mint problems reported.

The `rosdep` OS detection algorithm currently treats each Linux Mint release as an alias of the corresponding Ubuntu release. But apparently, there are enough differences for problems to arise.

For this to work smoothly, some Linux Mint users may need to contribute `rosdep` patches for [full Linux Mint OS support](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep/Tutorials/Add%20Support%20for%20an%20OS%20to%20rosdep).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you installing turtlesim from source? In that case, does `rosmake turtlesim` throw an error?

Maybe `rosdep` has problems detecting your operating system correctly. If turtlesim builds, I think you can safely ignore the rosdep error.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-09-14**:
I ran 'rosmake turtlesim' and it compiled with no errors.  The tutorial was just to get me up to speed to run a colleague's code. It fully compiles as well when I run rosmake on it, even though the other warnings pop up (like the boost one I posted, and similarly for libeigen3).  Thanks for the help